# C++ Error "_main", referenced from: " Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, class, object

I keep getting this error "_main", referenced from: ..." I'm new to C++ and Xcode can someone explain to me why I'm getting this error and what I need to do to fix it?
Thank you

[image]

```
#ifndef bank_h
#define bank_h
#include <iostream>
//using namespace std;
namespace bank_hw
{
    class bank
    {
        public:
            int accountNumber;
            std::string owner;
            std::string newOwner;
            double balance;
    
        public:
            //default constructor
            bank();
            bank(int accountNumber, std::string owner, double balance);
    
        //function to deposit
        void deposit(double amount);
    
        //function to withdraw
        void withdraw(double amount);
    
        //function will display acount info: current owner and current balance
        void displayInfo();
    
        //fucntion that will change ownder
        void newOwnder(bank& owner, std::string newOwner);
    
    };
}
#endif
```

Comment: Because your missing your `int main()` function to run your program

Comment: You probably needed to show `main.cpp` instead of the header.

Comment: I don't know xcode but the header usage seems strange to me in the xcode log.

Comment: I had a feeling it had to do something with main.cpp but this is supposed to be my class file and I'm not sure how to change main.cpp to a header file

Comment: ***and I'm not sure how to change main.cpp to a header file*** You certainly don't want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Every `c++` program need a global `main` function to run program.

```
// bank.hpp

namespace bank_hw
{
    class bank
    {
        public:
            int accountNumber;
    
        public:
            //default constructor
            bank();
    
    };
}
```

define your class member functions in another another `.cpp` file

```
// bank.cpp


using namespace bank_hw;

bank::bank(): accountNumber( 0 ) {}
```

and `#include` header `.hpp` file, where you running your `main` function.

```
#include "bank.hpp"

int main() {
    
    bank_hw::bank b;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: how do I change my file to be a .cpp or .h instead of a main.cpp?

Comment: `@Tiana Chargin`, are you asking, how to compile your `c++` program? `g++ -o main.exe main.cpp`

Comment: I was trying to have main, class, and implementation files all in different files and I think that was the problem. When I put all three in the same file the program runs. I guess the issue that I need to solve is how do I create all three files separately and still be able to use them when called on.

Comment: that's exactly I explained in my answer, create `.hpp` file to declare your `class`, and `#include` that .hpp file in your source `.cpp` file and define your class member functions, and create one separate `main.cpp` and #include your .hpp file and run the program.